# Nhibernate queryover matching two IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, repository-pattern, queryover

i have this domain objects:

```
public class Societa : EquatableObject<Societa>
{
    public virtual int IdSocieta { get; set; }
    public virtual string NomeSocieta { get; set; }
}

public class Attivita {
    public virtual int IdAttivita { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<ProcessoEsaminato> Processi
}

public class ProcessoEsaminato {
    public virtual ProcessoSocieta ProcessoCoperto { get; set; }
    public virtual int Anno { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessoSocieta {
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Societa SocietaDiretta { get; set; }
    public virtual Societa SocietaService { get; set; }
}

public class Processo   {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string NomeProcesso { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<ProcessoSocieta> SocietaAttivate
}
```

i nedd to extract from db with QueryOver or LinqToNHibernate every `Process` of an `Attivita` with `NomeProcesso`, `SocietaDiretta.NomeSocieta` and `SocietaService.NomeSocieta`

So i think:
i have to start from `Processo` and get those that in their `SocietaAttivate` has one that is in `Processi` collection of `Attivita`, looking at `ProcessoCoperto`  property of every element of this collection

i try this:

```
public IEnumerable<object> ProcessiPerAttivita (Attivita att) {     
    ProcessoSocieta ps = null;
    var elencoPS = att.Processi.Select(p => p.ProcessoCoperto).ToList<ProcessoSocieta>();

    return _session.QueryOver<Processo>()           
        .JoinAlias(processo => processo.SocietaAttivate, () => ps)
        .Where(x => x.SocietaAttivate.IsIn(elencoPS))
        .List();            
}
```

but `Where(x => x.SocietaAttivate.IsIn(elencoPS))` is not what i nedd, since it wants only a list of id. so first question is how can i do this?

Second question is how can i select only fields i need from different object, coming from different level of aggregation?

EDIT:

now i try

```
_session.QueryOver<Processo>()
            .JoinAlias(processo => processo.SocietaAttivate, () => ps)
            .Where(x => x.SocietaAttivate.Any(p => elencoPS.Contains(p)) != null)           
            .List();
```

but i get `variable 'x' of type 'ProcessoSocieta' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Processo> ProcessiPerAttivita (Attivita att) {     
    ProcessoSocieta ps = null;
    var elencoPS = att.Processi.Select(p => p.ProcessoCoperto).ToList<ProcessoSocieta>();

    return _session.QueryOver<Processo>()           
        .JoinAlias(processo => processo.SocietaAttivate, () => ps)
        .WhereRestrictionOn(processo  => ps.Id).IsIn(elencoPS.Select(el => el.Id).ToList())
        .List<Processo>();            
}
```

You must use the 'ps' alias!

Edit: you can use

```
.List<Processo>(); and return an IEnumerable<Processo>
```

Comment: .Where(x => ps.SocietaAttivate.IsIn(elencoPS)) does not compile and, as i try meantime IsIn only does not work with object collection

Comment: great! what's difference between WhereRestrictionOn and Where ?

Comment: It's the same, you narrow your query so the resultset suits your needs.
A good read: http://tpodolak.com/blog/2014/08/18/nhibernate-generating-where-in-or-queries/